# Border line MO-Math Stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Occasionally there are questions that are beyond the level of Math Stackexchange(they get few views and no responds) but also for whatever reason the consensus on MO is that such questions don't quite fit in MO scope. Is there any other forum that are more suitable for this type of questions?

Comment: That would depend on the exact question, wouldn't it? Also, "few views and no responds" need not indicate the level of the question, just the level of interest in the question, or the details of who's looking at math.stackexchange for the few minutes that the question stays on the front page.

Comment: Perhaps ([meta-tag:math-stackexchange]) might be a reasonable tag for this question. (And you might have a look at older questions in that tag to see whether there were some previous discussions related to your question.)

Comment: I agree with Gerry that "beyond the level of Math.SE" is often not the right explanation -- there are plenty of high-level discussions there. But the traffic there is immense and questions get buried; my theory is that people more often go for the low-hanging fruit than for the stuff up high that takes more effort. If you are referring to a question of your own, consider applying a bounty. Do you have something specific you'd like to refer to here?

Comment: I agree with you. I do not have any particular question in mind, but I took low views as a sign of "beyond the ..."Perhaps that is a rather naive point of view.

Comment: Since this is at least marginally related to your question, I will add also a link to this meta.math.SE post: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3478) (Perhaps also [other discussions linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478) might be of interest.)